# How to horizontally invert the input type="text" for Calculator?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Im doing a Simple Calculator using html, css and javascript.
I want to display the numbers on the right side of the input element?

How can I do that?

Is a better input type to use for a calculator?
Is a way to move the numbers to the right? Like a calculator?

Thank You !

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12114570/how-to-align-texts-inside-of-a-input

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend to use input `type="number"` so only numbers can be inserted. 
But you could also use input `type="text"` as it was intended to be.

You can achieve the displaying of the numbers on the right side with `text-align:right;` in CSS.

```css
#number1 {
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<input id="number1" type="number" />
```